# How does the @ModelAttribute annotation work? Why can't I got the value?

Tags: spring-mvc

Here is my code:

```
public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute("testVO") TestVO testVO){
    //test the VO work theory
    //testVO = new TestVO();
    testVO.setTestStr("this is my test!");
    return "index/index";
}
```

When I used the new to create a object for the testVO.
I can not get the value in my jsp page.
If I used set method, it works.

So, I think:
The object testVo has been create by the IOC container, so the JSP get the reference from the container, not the one I create by my self.

Am I right?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Post up the rest of your class. But by default the model attribute will be a new instance each time and the values will be set from whatever is present in the request data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You guessed it right. Below text is from spring docs:

```
An @ModelAttribute on a method argument indicates the argument should be 
retrieved from the model. If not present in the model, the argument should be
instantiated first and then added to the model.
```

If you want to create it yourself, you explicity need to add it to the model (as below) so that can be used in your jsp

```
public String login(Model model){

    TestVO testVO = new TestVO();
    testVO.setTestStr("this is my test!");

    model.addAttribute("testVO", testVO);
    return "index/index";
}
```

Comment: Here is the code in my jsp page. `<form:form commandName="testVO" action="login">
    TestVO: <form:input path="testStr"/>
   </form:form>`. I used the code you posted above, it works well. I thought that I should set a argument first in my method, so that the commandName can match the testVO. I was wrong, it just match it from the model. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Man, here is the best explanation of @ModelAttribute annotation:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods

Read at least two chapters. This will give you a theoretical knowledge.

A practical side of question you can find on my blog:

http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-form-handling/

I hope it will be helpful for you

Comment: Thank you Alex, you recognised me that I should read the API docs again. I found something new when I read it again, really thanks!